Mac screen sleeps shortly after Mac woken by pmset
I am waking my Mac mini (M2)every morning with the command:
sudo pmset repeat wake MTWRFSS 6:59:50

but after a few seconds the screen goes black.
In System Settings/Lock screen I have:

Start Screen Saver when inactive for 5min
Turn display off when inactive for 30 min
Require password after screen saver begins or display is turned off after 1 hour

So I am not expecting the screen to turn off after just a few seconds. Can anyone offer an explanation?
I am doing this (hopefully!) to allow Keyboard Maestro to complete a script that runs a SuperDuper! backup. The script works fine when the computer is fully awake, but stalls at its last action: click the 'Copy Now" button when it isn't.

Is there a reason you don't just set a schedule in SuperDuper to run the backup at 7:00 am every morning?

My Keyboard Maestro  script does schedule SuperDuper  to run at 7.00 am every day. It mounts the backup volume, opens SuperDuper, selects Scheduled copies from the window menu, and should press the 'Copy now' button but only does this automatically when the Mac and screen are awake.

I meant, why not just use Super Duper to do the scheduling and eliminate Keyboard Maestro from the process? You can set up scheduled backups directly in Super Duper. I have a backup run everyday at 8:30 am. SuperDuper even takes care of mounting and unmounting the backup drive.

Thank you: that's helpful. I had tried just using the SuperDuper scheduler before but it was sticking at the final  'target volume will dismount when SuperDuper quits' step, and not quitting. Not sure why, as it is now working OK. Thanks again.

This is correct and expected behaviour for a scheduled wake. macOS is looking for a reason to stay awake; specifically, macOS is looking for user activity or at least device input.
If there is no user activity within a short time after waking, macOS will return to sleep.
If a script or tool runs after the scheduled wake, the tool needs to create a power assertion asking macOS to keep the computer awake. Scripts can use the macOS caffeinate to create this assertion.
This behaviour is not formally documented by Apple but it has been this way for many major versions of macOS.

I moved the whole scheduling part to SuperDuper! alone, which took Keyboard Maestro out of the picture. This not only simplified the setup, it also works as expected now.
